# What to think of miraculous images? (Catholic view)

Tags: catholicism, miracles

There is some number of images of Jesus or other spiritual beings that are claimed to be miraculous as they miraculously got exposed in a camera. People who took these images swear there was no the image prior to the picture taking.

Some of the images of Jesus:

[image]
[image]

[Here is a site](http://jesusphotos.altervista.org/Jesus_face.htm) displaying many images of Jesus's face.

Did any of the theologians explain why they resemble the face of Jesus always in a different way? Hardly ever Jesus looks the same. In order to make this question about Christianity, what does the Catholic church say about these miraculous images? Some of the images claim to have the real or similar presence of Christ in them similar to the Eucharist. They also supposedly offer a special spiritual protection if hang in a house.